# Laravel database migrattion user could be from another type

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, migration

I'm currently facing an issue on the conception part of my project.
I read many posts and no one abort this problem.
I'm using Laravel 5.6 as API for my web App.

So I have two type of users :

1. Simple user
2. Professional user

The "Professional" one has a dashboard where he can do many stuffs, and the "Simple user" can contact the "Professional".

But the "Professional" could also be a "Simple user", he can contact other "Professional". And here is the problem I'm blocked on the conception of Model and Migration of the database. I don't know how to link them, and I don't want to duplicate all the "Simple user" vars in a "Professional" table and just add vars in this one. (Don't know if it's explicite)

So I started by create an User Model/Migration :

> App/User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password', 'old_password', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'birthday', 'address',
        'postal_code', 'city', 'country', 'phone_number'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id', 'password', 'old_password', 'remember_token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be handled by Carbon
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'birthday'
    ];
}
```

> database/migrations/..create_users_table.php

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('old_password');
            $table->string('phone_number', 50);
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->tinyInteger('sex');
            $table->date('birthday');
            $table->text('address');
            $table->string('postal_code', 10);
            $table->string('city', 50);
            $table->string('country', 50);
            $table->boolean('valid_email')->default(false);

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

The the Professional Model/Migration :

> App/Professional.php

namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Professional extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'profession', 'organisation', 'subscription', 'activity_start_at', 'valid_num_organisation'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'user_id', 'num_organisation'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be handled by Carbon
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'activity_start_at'
    ];

}
```

> database/migrations/..create_professionals_table.php

```
class CreateProfessionalsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('professionals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->primary('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('profession');
            $table->string('organisation');
            $table->string('num_organisation');
            $table->string('subscription');
            $table->date('activity_start_at');
            $table->boolean('valid_num_organisation')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('professionals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('professionals_user_id_foreign');
            $table->dropColumn('user_id');
        });
        Schema::dropIfExists('professionals');
    }
}
```

**And here is the real question what the best way to link User and the Professional ? Like a "user->isOneOf()" or something like that.**

I was thinking about create a role on my user and if role is empty the user is "Simple user" and if not is a professional but I pretty sur is not the best way.

I also look at the polymorphic link but i don't think it's the one I need in this case.

If you have any ideas I'm listening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you for the extensive description of your problem. Not everyone does that.

Of course, most of this answer is somewhat opinion based. There are many different ways to implement this kind of behaviour. But I think the 'correct' implementation for this problem should be discussed because there are a lot of developers who really don't know where to start on this topic. I am happy to accept any feedback or additions to my answer to make it more complete.

So. Most of the time when I have to deal with more than one type/variant of the same entity, I use just 1 table. Especially when dealing with authentication. Because that makes coding a Laravel application a lot easier.

In the case of just 2 different types of entities. (A normal user and a professional user in your case), I just ad a `is_professional` boolean flag on the `users` table. That would be sufficient.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-auth-multi-user-type

When you want to use more different variants, I'd add a `role` column to the table. This could be a `role_id` integer to reference a seperate `roles` table if you need to store role specific data. But most of the time you can get away with just using a `varchar` role key. You can also use an `enum` for this but I never do. I always ran into problems when migrating the table later. Don't know for sure if they fixed those problems already.

There is no shame in storing extra data in your `users` table that only is filled for certain types of users. In your case that would be the `profession` and `organisation` columns for example. Denormalization is accepted in some of this cases. This totally depends on the size and use of your data.

http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/denormalization-when-why-and-how

If denormalization is not the way to go in your application. You could also create a seperate table for any additional information for the `professional_users` in your case. You should write some logic that makes sure you can load additional information for your model. Maybe in the `boot` method. Or maybe as a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes).

If you want. You can also create completely different authentication systems for both users. Separating logic when logging in. But when you do that, you have to choose which user can access a certain page. It would be hard to implement accessibility for both types of users I think.

https://scotch.io/@sukelali/how-to-create-multi-table-authentication-in-laravel

Like I said, there is no general ideal implementation for your problem. To answer your question in particular I would have to know your application from top to bottom. Only the developer, you ;), can form the most optimal tactics. Maybe that was not the answer you were looking for but it's the best answer I can give.

Comment: Well, first of all thanks for your very detailed answer and all these links very helpful. After discutions with the team we all agree to go on the `is_professional` solution. I'll also look at the `professional_user` solution, and see how to deal with scope in this case (I don't know how it works). I think is a nice discutions subject that could be nice if there is other point of view. Thanks.